# Cloudfoundry spring java 7

Tags: java, spring, cloud-foundry

Does Cloudfoundry have support for Java 7? Can I deploy a Spring Application compiled with Java 7?

Thanks,
Cristian

Comment: https://twitter.com/cloudfoundry/status/220932249523204096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES.** New Cloud Foundry eclipse integration release supports java7 application. Java 7 is also now supported for Grails, Java Web and Spring applications.
Visit [this link](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/09/13/cloud-foundry-integration-for-eclipse-now-supports-standalone-java-applications-and-java-7/) to learn more about this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How about Tomcat 7? I saw that you can deploy a web app in Tomcat 7 as a standalone app, but how about via STS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can deploy an Java application and specify a Java 7 runtime using vmc push --runtime=java7

There is a template for deploying Tomcat 7 applications https://github.com/ericbottard/cloudfoundry-tomcat-7 but I'm not sure whether you can do that from within STS at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow the instruction given in this link https://github.com/ericbottard/cloudfoundry-tomcat-7, and it will deploy. Nevertheless you may get sometimes an error caused by tomcat saying that there is "too many open files".
2. Also bear in mind that you need to add to your POM.xml el-2.2.jar along with an expression factory in web.xml to have it working (obviously if you use the functionality of el-2.2) because it still uses libraries from tomcat 6 which does not support el-2.2